# Understand normalized squared euclidean distance?

Tags: statistics, wolfram-mathematica, formula, algebra, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to understand the normalized squared euclidean distance formula from the [Wolfram documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance.html):

```
1/2*Norm[(u-Mean[u])-(v-Mean[v])]^2/(Norm[u-Mean[u]]^2+Norm[v-Mean[v]]^2)
```

I searched around for this formula on the web but couldn't find it. Can someone explain how this formula is derived?

Comment: this is outside the scope of stack overflow. Please follow the community guidelines for posting questions.

Comment: I believe this is a statistical measure with no meaningful interpretation in terms of geometric vectors. note it can also be written `1/2*Variance[u - v]/(Variance[u] + Variance[v])`.  In any case off topic, take it to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: another discussion here http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1114109 (Probably a better place for this..)

Answer (score 2):

Meaning of this formula is the following:

> Distance between two vectors where there lengths have been scaled to
>   have unit norm. This is helpful when the direction of the vector is
>   meaningful but the magnitude is not.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136232/definition-of-normalized-euclidean-distance

Comment: not a really satisfactory explination, do you understand it, can you elaborate.  Note the calculation is *not* independent of the magnitudes.

Comment: `NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}] =!= 
 EuclideanDistance[Normalize[{a, b, c}], Normalize[{d, e, f}]]`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Can you give me an example please? I try to make one with vectors [1,2,3] and [3,5,10] (from [Wolfram documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance.html)) but i don't know which normalization method i have to use for vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Luca's comment, here is an example showing the "*distance between two vectors where their lengths have been scaled to have unit norm*".  It doesn't equal the normalised square Euclidean distance. The former is coloured blue in the graphic below.  The standard Euclidean distance is coloured red.

```
(* Leave this unevaluated to see symbolic expressions *)
{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}} = {{1, 2, 3}, {3, 5, 10}};

N[EuclideanDistance[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]]
```

> 7.87401

```
Norm[{a, b, c} - {d, e, f}]

SquaredEuclideanDistance[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]

Norm[{a, b, c} - {d, e, f}]^2

N[NormalizedSquaredEuclideanDistance[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]]
```

> 0.25

```
(1/2 Norm[({a, b, c} - Mean[{a, b, c}]) - ({d, e, f} - Mean[{d, e, f}])]^2)/
 (Norm[{a, b, c} - Mean[{a, b, c}]]^2 + Norm[{d, e, f} - Mean[{d, e, f}]]^2)

1/2 Variance[{a, b, c} - {d, e, f}]/(Variance[{a, b, c}] + Variance[{d, e, f}])

{a2, b2, c2} = Normalize[{a, b, c}];
{d2, e2, f2} = Normalize[{d, e, f}];

N[EuclideanDistance[{a2, b2, c2}, {d2, e2, f2}]]
```

> 0.120185

```
Graphics3D[{Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}], 
  Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 5, 10}}],
  Red, Thick, Line[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 5, 10}}],
  Blue, Line[{{a2, b2, c2}, {d2, e2, f2}}]},
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}},
 AxesLabel -> Map[Style[#, Bold, 16] &, {"x", "y", "z"}],
 AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
 ViewPoint -> {1.275, -2.433, -1.975}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0.551, -0.778, 0.302}]
```

[image]